# Show Logback error when I run Simple Spring Boot project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I follow this tutorial to create spring boot project, when I run the project, it shows an error. Please help me to fix it.

[image: stack trace]

my pom.xml

[image: pom.xml]

Comment: this tutorial is http://blog.xuite.net/hs19890622/job/385041630-%E5%BB%BA%E7%AB%8B%E7%B0%A1%E5%96%AE%E7%9A%84spring+boot+%E5%B0%88%E6%A1%88

Comment: How did you build + how did you launch the app ? (I see boot.maven.. in the stacktrace)

Comment: Run As->Melvin build and Goals: spring-boot:run , and then click Run button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that it worked with gradle but not Maven.

One possible solution is to delete your local maven repository to force it to redownload the dependencies:

- Go to your home folder and remove the folder `~/.m2/repository`.
  Then, try rebuilding your project with maven : `mvn clean install`

Answer (score 0):

I try to update Java and Maven,but it also do not work,and then I change **Maven to Gradle**,the application can run! Maybe Maven has problem.